# std::this_thread::sleep_for implementation depends on system clock

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

The problem I've encountered is that `std::this_thread::sleep_for` actually uses system clock to calculate the wake time (at least on Windows), not the steady clock. This produces problems when system clock is changed. E.g. if I have a waiting loop with a short wait interval (say 50 ms) and then I set the system clock back for 2 minutes, the loop will stall for 2 minutes instead of 50 ms. That is counterintuitive. I expect it to be 50 ms (+ some small deviation). In any other case this function doesn't make sense if it is possible to wake at random time.

The documentation on `sleep_for` function says that it is possible to use system clock, but i suppose that is a flaw in the standard. At least there should be a choice of the clock type to use. Or (better) the standard should require the clock to be steady.

So, considering such a flaw, do you know of any other platform-independent way to sleep for definite amount of time?

Comment: Just to clarify: When you say "Windows" do you mean Visual Studio? Because standard-library implementations are usually bound to the *compiler* and not the target platform.

Comment: cppreference.com: [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for?): _The standard recommends that a steady clock is used to measure the duration. If an implementation uses a system clock instead, the wait time may also be sensitive to clock adjustments._ That addresses exactly your issue. If your platform does run into this issue (I'm afraid it's mine too), it's simply bad implemented or cannot do better due to OS limitations.

Comment: Looks like a [bug in MSVC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169569/this-threadsleep-for-hangs-when-system-clock-moved.html).

Comment: By the way boost::this_thread::sleep_for has the same implementation unfortunately. And it can be implemented better on Windows - just use system Sleep funtion.

Answer (score 3):

A [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/3914) to address this issue was merged on Oct 21, 2023.

According to [change log](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/wiki/Changelog#vs-2022-179) it landed into VS 2022 17.9, which was first released as a non-Preview version on **February 2024**, according to the [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-9-now-available/).

Basically, it makes `this_thread::sleep_for` using `Sleep` Windows API function directly. So a possible workaround for earlier VS is to use that directly.

There are other places in synchronization facilities still affected by this bug, like `condition_variable::sleep_for`, a [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pulls) to fix these is merged, so hopefully the bug will be completely fixed this year.