# std::this_thread::sleep_for() sleep forever when changing OS date/time

Tags: c++, sleep

I found `std::this_thread::sleep_for()/sleep_until()` may sleep forever when OS datetime changed during sleep.

Here is a sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        //Sleep(500);
        std::cout << std::to_string(i) + "\n";
    }
}
```

When the program is running, I change the OS time a month ahead, then the program stop printing.
If I switch to Windows's Sleep() API, it works as expected.

It is a bug for `std::this_thread::sleep_for()/sleep_until()` or do I miss something?

**Note**: I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10 Pro 1909.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494992/stdthis-threadsleep-for-implementation-depends-on-system-clock

Comment: Thank you! I will use WIndows OS API for now.